# NSAttributedString throws NSInvalidArgumentException NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a swift method that is being used to clean HTML out of dirty text, as follows:

```
@objc public extension NSAttributedString {
    /**
     Initializes an `NSAttributedString` from a passed-in string
     */
    convenience init?(html: String) {
        let stringWithLineBreaks = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
        let htmlData = Data(stringWithLineBreaks.utf8)
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
        } else {
            print("Failed to parse HTML into NSAttributedString")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

This method works fine when being called from swift. However, when calling from Objective C as such:

```
NSString *test1 = @"<b>This is bold</b>";
NSAttributedString *test2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHtml:test1];
```

I get the following error and Stack Trace:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20421af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2049e77f _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2049c9a7 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithCapacity:].cold.1 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20323ee6 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 154
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2040d2e2 __createArray + 47
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2040d2a5 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 25
7   Provision                           0x0000000109782e78 -[RootViewController gotoViewController:animated:] + 1464
8   Provision                           0x0000000109b2b5b0 -[AppDelegate gotoHome:animated:] + 704
9   Provision                           0x0000000109b4b9a5 -[AppDelegate performPostSuccessfulLoginActions] + 1029
10  Provision                           0x0000000109b4b594 __36-[AppDelegate checkStartupActions]_block_invoke + 164
11  Provision                           0x0000000109b4f557 -[AppDelegate showInterstitialsComplete:] + 1271
12  Provision                           0x0000000109b4b412 -[AppDelegate checkStartupActions] + 2418
13  Foundation                          0x00007fff208318a9 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 415
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20390c57 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2039072a __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 926
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038fcdd __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 265
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a35e __CFRunLoopRun + 1949
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203896d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
19  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff23a6757c -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1847
20  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff23a684b1 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString] + 22
21  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff239e8d3a _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 9439
22  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff239e67e6 -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:] + 144
```

I have confirmed that the string is being passed in and is not null, and that the `htmlData` is created successfully and is also not null.

Comment: Works fine for me... have you stepped through in Debug to confirm that's the line causing the error?

Comment: @DonMag Are you calling it from Objective-C? I have stepped through the code, it always fails on the `try? NSAttributedString` line.

Comment: Quick example here: https://github.com/DonMag/ObjCSwift

Comment: I guess then that `[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]` is causing the issue. Could you check if you add `let options: [NS...: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]` if it's the one causing the issue?

Comment: @Larme I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @Wesley - did you try my sample project, and see it working?